# Erratic Pointer Please Advise on Overcoming This

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

Regarding my Acer E1-572P Touchscreen. Windows 10.

The screen pointer is overactive and behaves erratically on 2 websites, telescope.org and CoCalc. This is the problem.

I haven't found any other web sites which cause this behaviour. So all other websites that I use work fine. However I use these two web sites almost daily.

When I am at the mouse and keyboard the pointer will jump away from the mouse position, it will click on tabs and hyperlinks as though it had a mind of its own. The same happens when I am not at the keyboard or mouse. Also it will zoom in or out arbitrarily. It is so severe that I am unable to process my jobs. Sometimes there a line of bubble shapes about 1cm diameter appears.

I have tried Internet explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and the problem is the same with them all. Disabling the touch screen solves the problem but I need the screen working in touch mode for other uses.

The screen has been replaced (solving a more widespread problem) leaving these two websites still problematic.

These sites work perfectly on my smartphone and on other computers. I don't wish to disable JavaScript.

I would like to have your view on possible causes and solutions please. Also any idea of other websites which might produce this problem. Surely there can't be only 2.

Thanks Scriptham

Comment: and what happens if you *temporarily* disable JavaScript?

Comment: Using telescope.org in Chrome browser with JavaScript disabled: There is less erratic behaviour but it is not completely eliminated. The site is pretty much unusable.

Comment: try (2) using another mouse (and disabling original one) (3) disabling all laptop's built-in pointing devices using Device Manager (4) moving your computer away from sources of radio waves, e.g. to another room (5) anti-virus scan using some quality software like ESET (5) controlling mouse pointer using [MouseKeys](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000542.htm) (6) accessing your computer using Remote Desktop from another computer (7) accessing the site from Safe mode of Windows What will make the difference?